# I would like to virtualize an existing Raspberry Pi 4. Goals are to preserve its setup, avoid losing it due to SD card corruption, and increase speed

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, virtualization

I built a RPi 4 with UniFi, WireGuard and Pi Hole. Thankfully I made a copy of the SD card, and took an image of it, because the first card stopped working (it got super slow and then just stopped responding). I've had problems like this in the past, so I am sure it's SD corruption related.

I also have a Windows machine on all the time, and it has Hyper-V installed. I would love to be able to use the image of the SD card to make a VM from it, so I can decom the RPi.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: hyper-v won't help, since the pi CPU is not even closely related to what's in your windows PC ... you need the right type of *emulator* (the wrong type emulates the speed as well as the functionality of the pi - what's the point, right)

Comment: How will adding another level of emulation possibly increase performance? If you need a Linux PC, just install Debian on it (possibly in a VM if you need Windows too).

Comment: It seems strange that NONE of the experienced Pi users seem to have these mysterious SD Card problems. SD Cards do wear out and occasionally need to be replaced, but even this is rare.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. I've been using Pis since the first model, have run countless signage boards and other projects with them, and have always used proper PSUs and shutdown procedures. None of this stops them from eventually slowing down or failing in various ways. In any case, if this is such a problem for so many users, maybe it's not their fault.

Comment: I agree it's probably not the best option to try to virtualize this. I was just hoping not to have to go through the setup exercise again but I think that's what I'm going to end up doing. Thanks for the input to all.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi uses an ARM processor, your MS Windows machine uses an intel or amd processor so with a virtual machine manager (VMM) you cannot use the hardware supported virtual management of the machines processor. You have to use full virtualization with also emulating the processor. QEMU is known to support this but it is also known that it is annoying slow with full virtualization. So for my opinion you have a better solution using a VMM with hardware accelerated virtual management as usual on the MS Windows machine and install a Debian virtual machine on it with the same configuration that you have on the RasPi.

Answer (score 2):

Docker may help you. In this case, you have two choices. You can run the image file which you have read from SD-card to a Linux/Windows docker environment. I didn't test it on windows but the link below may be helpful if you install a Linux machine on your MS Hyper-V:

[How to Build and Run ARM Docker Images on x86 Hosts](https://matchboxdorry.gitbooks.io/matchboxblog/content/blogs/build_and_run_arm_images.html)

On the other hand, you can turn your raspberry pi on and use docker to cooperate with a better system (a high-performance machine) to handle/run services if you are concerned about the performance of your raspberry pi.